# What Techniques are Available in Reducing Branch Penalty with Compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction

Suppose you're writing a compiler that must handle branch prediction optimally. What techiniques are available? The case, of course, is in a heavilty pipelined applications. I have tried to google it, with no luck.

Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two general approaches:

- static branch prediction, based on heuristics (e.g. `if (p == NULL)` is predicted non-taken)
- profile-guided branch prediction, with the probability of taking either branch is deduced from a previous run of the (unoptimized) program on test inputs.